# How to hide parent tabbar when pushing controller in navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application with a tab bar controller and each view contains a navigation controller. My MainWindow looks as follows: [Image here http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?7bc867a594.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?7bc867a594.png)

Everything works fine as it is but I noticed a problem when pushing a details view to the navigation controller. In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath for a tableviewcontroller that belongs to the tab bar controller (the one called Latest in the image) I am doing this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ArticleViewController *articleController = [[ArticleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ArticleView" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:articleController animated:YES];

    [articleController release];
    articleController = nil;
}
```

The ArticleViewController has its own tabbar because it needs to display different things. The problem is that when I push the ArticleViewController into the navigationController I see both tabbars at the bottom of the view. Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 103, accepted):

After spending hours and posting a question here I found that the solution to this problem is adding the following line after the instantiation of ArticleController.

```
articleController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

Comment: the important note was set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` immediately after creating targetViewController

Answer (score 37):

If you prefer storyboard configuration over coding there is a toggle for that. Just go destinationViewController > Attribute Inspector:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why this was down-voted but this did work for me.

Answer (score 17):

A very simple solution:

```
 destinationViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

In your case:

```
 articleController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

You can simple hide parent tabbar through storyboard .

Select **viewcontroller** > **Attribute Inspector** > *check* **Hide Bottom Bar on Push**

Answer (score 5):

You can add below code in the view controller, which you are pushing.

```
-(BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
{ 
     return YES;
}
```

This will hide the tabbar in the pushed view controller only and as you pop the view controller tabbar remains unhide in rest all view controllers.

Swift version (3.x and above)

```
override var hidesBottomBarWhenPushed: Bool {
    get {
        return navigationController?.topViewController == self
    }
    set {
        super.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = newValue
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Save my time :)

Answer (score 2):

for swift 3,write the same code by you unhide the tabbar before pushviewController code like below

```swift
var frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
frame?.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - (frame?.size.height)!+112
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
  self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = frame!
})
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

or use just whant to unhide the tabbar u can use

```
viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
```

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP0MO.png)

Go to interface builder in Xcode -> open attribute inspector and check the item 'Hide Bottom bar on Push' for view controller you don't want to show tab bar. It will work!!

Answer (score 1):

Use property `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` in the controller that you want to hide.

For hide, all controllers put into `prepare for segue`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    segue.destination.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}
```