# Tab Bar application with a Navigation Controller but different tab bar on detail page

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4

I've seen lots of tutorials on how to build a simple app with 2 tabs and a navigation controller - especially when there is a table view where you click a row to see details (and have built this myself).  But most apps I've seen have the detail view such that either the tab bar disappears or there is another type of nav bar at the bottom.  Does anybody know how to extend the basic navigation controller and tab bar to get it to work to get it to work like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my question

[How to hide parent tabbar when pushing controller in navigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947680/how-to-hide-parent-tabbar-when-pushing-controller-in-navigationcontroller)