# Xcode Multiple viewcontrollers for a Tab in a TabBar Controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller, tabbar

I have multiple viewcontrollers for a single tab in a tabbar controller.

In the initial viewcontroller, it shows the tabbar with two items. There is also a button that takes you to the second viewcontroller. I want the second viewcontroller to have the initial tabbar controller with the two items. It currently displays no tabbar controller.

How do I achieve this?

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! I solved my own question.

I was using the "present modally" segue, when instead, the "show" segue will automatically include the root tabbar and navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try embedding the two view controllers in a container, and only show the container from the tabbar controller. This way you can only realod what is inside the container, and the tabs will be always visible.

Answer (score 0):

use this methood in the `UIViewController` class where you want to hide/not hide the `tabBarController`

```
-(BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
{
    return NO;
}
```

*See also :* [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947680/how-to-hide-parent-tabbar-when-pushing-controller-in-navigationcontroller) is the exact opposite to yours, but see if you can make some use of it.