# Navigation Based App With Tab Hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tabbar

How to hide `tabbar` in Navigation Flow?

```
self.tabbarController.tabbar.hidden = true
```

This is not working. I called this from `ViewWillAppear` method.

Comment: kindly some more information or code that you are are trying.

Comment: can you post your complete code here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide parent tabbar when pushing controller in navigationController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947680/how-to-hide-parent-tabbar-when-pushing-controller-in-navigationcontroller)

Comment: try `UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just check the `Hide Bottom Bar on Push` for your ViewController if you're using storyboard

Comment: ****Not Working

Comment: @JaydeepModi it should be checked not unchecked. Sorry for that screenshot

Comment: but it works on mine?? how do you push viewcontrollers?